# Why is my picture getting blurring after switching CIFilter?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, core-image, cifilter

After changing the CIFilter on an imageView image, the image appears blurry. Trying to figure out why.

Here is the code:

```
- (UIImage *)convertImageToGrayScale:(UIImage *)image {
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPhotoEffectTonal"];
    CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
    [filter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    return [UIImage imageWithCIImage:filter.outputImage];
}

- (UIImage *)convertImageToColorScale:(UIImage *)image {
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPhotoEffectChrome"];
    CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
    [filter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    return [UIImage imageWithCIImage:filter.outputImage];
}


- (IBAction)colorize:(id)sender {
    self.imageView.image = nil;
    if(self.hasColor) {
        self.hasColor = FALSE;
        self.imageView.image = [self convertImageToGrayScale:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:self.filePath]];
        NSLog(@"remove Color");
    }
    else {
        self.hasColor = TRUE;
        self.imageView.image = [self convertImageToColorScale:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:self.filePath]];
        NSLog(@"Add Color");
    }
}
```

When I add the filter the first time, it looks good. When I click the button to change the filter, it's blurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the line `return [UIImage imageWithCIImage:filter.outputImage];` with:

```
CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
CGImageRef imageRef = [[CIContext contextWithOptions:nil] createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:outputImage.extent];
UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
return newImg;
```